# Node.js - winston-loggly module throws "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error

Tags: node.js, logging, sails.js

I am trying to setup Winston Loggly in my Sails.js application. I followed the [Sails.js - Using A Custom Logger](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-log#?using-a-custom-logger) documentation and setup my `/config/log.js` file like this:

```
// Send logs to Loggly using Winston
var winston = require('winston');
require('winston-loggly');

var customLogger = new winston.Logger();
customLogger.add(winston.transports.Loggly, {
    inputToken: MY INPUT TOKEN,
    auth: {
        username: MY USERNAME,
        password: MY PASSWORD
    },
    subdomain: MY SUBDOMAIN,
    level: 'info',
    tags: ['web-service', process.env.NODE_ENV],
    json: true
});

module.exports.log = {

    level: 'info',
    custom: customLogger,

    // Disable captain's log so it doesn't prefix or stringify our meta data.
    inspect: false

};
```

No matter what I do, I get the following error in my console:

```
/Users/Nag/Code/web-service/node_modules/winston-loggly/node_modules/loggly/lib/loggly/client.js:190
    return isSolid.test(tag) && tag.length <= 64;
                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at /Users/Nag/Code/web-service/node_modules/winston-loggly/node_modules/loggly/lib/loggly/client.js:190:36
    at Array.filter (native)
    at Loggly.tagFilter (/Users/Nag/Code/web-service/node_modules/winston-loggly/node_modules/loggly/lib/loggly/client.js:186:15)
    at new exports.Loggly (/Users/Nag/Code/web-service/node_modules/winston-loggly/node_modules/loggly/lib/loggly/client.js:62:12)
    at Object.exports.createClient (/Users/Nag/Code/web-service/node_modules/winston-loggly/node_modules/loggly/lib/loggly/client.js:30:10)
    at new exports.Loggly (/Users/Nag/Code/web-service/node_modules/winston-loggly/lib/winston-loggly.js:50:24)
    at Logger.add (/Users/Nag/Code/web-service/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:475:41)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Nag/Code/web-service/config/log.js:18:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/include-all/index.js:129:29
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at requireAll (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/include-all/index.js:44:9)
    at buildDictionary (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-build-dictionary/index.js:68:14)
    at Function.module.exports.aggregate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-build-dictionary/index.js:190:9)
    at Array.loadOtherConfigFiles (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/moduleloader/index.js:239:27)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:591:38
    at _arrayEach (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:85:13)
```

I can't seem to resolve this. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error seems to point to that, for some reason, your **process.env.NODE_ENV** is null, empty or undefined. 
Could you check that ?

Comment: That was it! Whew! I just removed it and it worked. Strange, not sure why `process.env.NODE_ENV` is undefined there.

Comment: `process.env.NODE_ENV` is going to be empty there unless you start Sails w/ (for example) `NODE_ENV=production sails lift`, or if you have NODE_ENV set in your environment (via `export NODE_ENV=whatever`, on Linux).  Current versions of Sails actually _set_ `NODE_ENV` to whatever the current Sails environment is, which can be a little confusing and will be going away in Sails 1.0.